# Parallel random numbers julia

Tags: random, julia, montecarlo

Consider the basic iteration to generate `N` random numbers and save them in an array (assume either that we are not interested in array comprehensions and also that we don't know the calling `rand(N)`)

```
function random_numbers(N::Int)
array = zeros(N)
for i in 1:N
    array[i] = rand()
end
array
end
```

I am interested in a similar function that takes advantage of the cores of my laptop to generate the same array. I have checked [this nice blog](http://corysimon.github.io/articles/parallel-monte-carlo-in-julia/) where the macros `@everywhere`, `@spawn` and `@parallel` are introduced but there the calculation is carried out "on-the-fly" and an array is not needed to save the data.

I have the impression that this is very basic and can be done easily using perhaps the function `pmap` but I am unfamiliar with parallel computing.

My aim is to apply this method to a function that I have built to generate random numbers drawn from an unusual distribution.

Comment: So let's get back down to facts: **[1]** What have you tried so far? **[2]** Where are the collected results? **[3]** What was missing in the collected results v/s some set of your prior expectations and what have you tested in attempts to better match the former with the latter ones? Be rather clear in posting these facts and quantitative, all that definitely before ever shouting on the Community members *( cit. )* "***Any ideas?***", that's ultimately impolite, right?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `result = @parallel (vcat) for i in 1:ncores random_numbers(N) end` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comment more clarification in the question is always welcome. However, it seems `pmap` will do what is required. The relevant documentation is [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/parallel-computing#Parallel-Map-and-Loops-1).

The following is a an example. Note, the time spent in the `pmap` method is half of the regular `map`. With 16 cores, the situation might be substantially better:

```
julia> addprocs(2)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3

julia> @everywhere long_rand() = foldl(+,0,(randn() for i=1:10_000_000))

julia> long_rand()
-1165.9596619177153

julia> @time map(x->long_rand(), zeros(10,10))
  8.455930 seconds (204.89 k allocations: 11.069 MiB)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
   ⋮
   ⋮ 

julia> @time pmap(x->long_rand(), zeros(10,10));
  6.125479 seconds (773.08 k allocations: 42.242 MiB, 0.25% gc time)

julia> @time pmap(x->long_rand(), zeros(10,10))
  4.609745 seconds (20.99 k allocations: 954.991 KiB)
10×10 Array{Float64,2}:
   ⋮
   ⋮
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the definition of the function `long_rand()`?  So in the function `addprocs` I pass the number of cores, right? What do you think about the @Liso comment? This achieves my original goal but I am very intriguing about this way you present the solution

Comment: First, Liso comment describes another way of doing the same - quite similar. The definition of `long_rand` is just a processing wasteful calculation of a random value (by adding a lot of random normal variables) used as a placeholder for the complex calculation you wish to do.

Comment: @dapias If you do `addprocs` then `ncores = length(procs())` gives you actual number of worker processes. (see also rmprocs) @DanGetz I am still newbie and very impressed by pmap performance! :) I tested `@time @parallel (hcat) for i in 1:3 map(x->long_rand(), zeros(10)) end` with 4 worker processes. Although less allocation its speed was slower than `@time pmap(x->long_rand(), zeros(10,3))`. And if I changed (around 40_000 times slower) long_rand to rand then your solution was comparably fast to map function! :)

Comment: `nworkers()` and `nprocs()` give the number of workers and processes, respectively. The number of workers is what one would want to split the work on. Also, it is important to mention threading is also a route to parallel processing, but it is experimental (but the docs explain all of this and more).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to do a more careful initialization of random number generators in parallel processes, e.g:

```
# choose the seed you want
@everywhere srand(1)
# replace 10 below by maximum process id in your case
@everywhere const LOCAL_R = randjump(Base.GLOBAL_RNG, 10)[myid()]
# here is an example usage
@everywhere f() = rand(LOCAL_R)
```

In this way you:

- make sure that your results are reproducible;
- have control that there is no overlap between random sequences generated by different processes.

Comment: In DanGetz answer you could write `@everywhere long_rand() = foldl(+,0,(randn(LOCAL_R) for i=1:10_000_000))` everything else remains unchanged.

Comment: It is important to note that  this does not make the results reproducible with `pmap` parallelization, since the order in which procs are assigned will (almost surely) differ in each run. However, It does make the results reproducible for `@parallel` loops.